# Where are game apps' storage files saved? I would like to delete them

Tags: storage

I installed The Trail on my Moto E 4. 
I uninstalled it. But, I thought I might try the game again. So, I reinstalled it. But, the game started up from where I left off the first time.
So, how do I get rid of the previous game data files?
It seemed like the second installation took a lot less time.

I am new to these larger games. I have tried a few of the smaller ones like Float Plane. (Are files for that game still on my phone, too?)

I do have a File Manager app.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to **Settings > Apps > The Trail > Storage** then click **Clear Data** and **Clear Cache**

If The Trail requires you to log into an account or Google Play Games than either delete the account data, or create a new account.

Comment: This answer is unlikely to be helpful because the OP has already said he *uninstalled and reinstalled*.

Comment: That is correct. The app is not listed in Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Game save data is found at:

```
/sdcard/Android/data/[package.name.of.app]
```

And it's running resources collection, familiar as obb file is at

```
/sdcard/Android/obb/[package.name.of.app]
```

Incase obb is not visible and you're sure it is not yet deleted, you have root, and a root file manager find it at

```
/data/media/obb/[package.name.of.app]
```

Delete it and you'll be free from that. If it's undeletable. Delete it when device is off with TWRP recovery File Manager. Usually this results from invalid permissions set to the folder or file in the folder though it's less unlikely if you have not been running root in your device

That's all you need